# How to get an NSArray that is returned from a getter method?

Tags: objective-c

*Note: This question has been updated with suggestions supplied in answers below in which to bring a fuller context to the present state of the problem.*

You may view complete project files here: https://github.com/cxx6xxc/Skeleton/blob/master/README.md

**Conditions**

1. I create an `NSArray` in an object's `init` method.
2. I return the NSArray with it's get method.

**Problem**

Upon arrival, the NSArray is null.

### Creating instance

Attempt 1:

*This is my original implementation.*

```
- (id)init:
{
    labels = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Red", @"Green", @"Blue", nil];

    return self;    
}
```

Attempt 2:

*Ismael suggested I wrap it with a sub-classing protocol.*

*neo suggested I retain the NSArray.*

```
- (id)init:
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        labels = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Red", @"Green", @"Blue", nil];

        [labels retain];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Attempt 3:

*Anoop Vaidya suggested I force ownership with alloc and NSMutableArray:*

```
- (id)init:
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        labels = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Red", @"Green", @"Blue", nil];
    }
    return self;
}
```

But, when I return the object, despite the different init suggestions cited above...

### Returning the object

```
- (NSArray *)getLabels 
{
    return labels; 
}
```

*...with NSMutableArray...*

```
- (NSMutableArray *)getLabels 
{
    return labels; 
}
```

... the NSArray getter returns a null object.

### Calling the method

```
int main(void)
{
    id view;
    view = [ZZView alloc];

    id model;
    model = [ZZModel alloc];

    id controller;
    controller = [[ZZController alloc] init: model: view];

    labels = [[controller getModel] getLabels];

    if(labels)
        NSLog(@"allocated");
    else
        NSLog(@"not alloced");

    [view dealloc];
    [model dealloc];
    [controller dealloc];

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Question**

What am I not doing, missing or what am I doing wrong that causes the null return value?

Comment: how are you instantiating your class? there's an `init:` method there that troubles me, because it has no arguments, so what you posted will not build

Comment: try self.labels = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Red", @"Green", @"Blue", nil];

Comment: why dont you use NSMutableArray, instead of NSArray

Comment: @Ismael, I'm statically declaring, so there is no need to send init args.  That I know of?

Comment: I meant show some code, the error is most likely there

Comment: You need to retain it even you declaring statically. The reference count is zero as the array is auto released when it goes out from the function scope. Please refers to my answer.

Comment: @neo I retained it.  It still is being returned as null.

Answer (score 2):

`init` methods need to call some [super init], so you will need to do something like this:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        labels = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Red", @"Green", @"Blue", nil];
    }
    return self;    
}
```

Edit: looking at your git repo, I found

```
controller = [[ZZController alloc] init: model: view];
```

I'm not entirely sure how the compiler interprets the empty arguments, but my guess is that it reads them as nil, and therefore your ZZController doesn't have model

Also, you have some messy argument order, the first argument (with text `init:`) is your model, and your second argument (with text `model:`) is your view
(this according to your `- (id)init: (ZZModel*)Model: (ZZView*)View`

In order to make it work quickly, you should do

```
controller = [[ZZController alloc] init:model model:view];
```

I'm gonna take a (short) leap here and guess you are new to iOS development, so I'll recommend that you read about objc programming, how to write functions, how to send multiple parameters, so on and so forth, and after that, do some refactoring

Cheers!

Comment: I thought this was only necessary to subclass, I thought self was always sent unobserved as first argument.

Comment: I added the above convention to my init method, but did not solve this issue.  NSArray is still null.

Comment: How are you creating this class and how are you calling the getLabels? show the code of how you handle it from outside, I'm pretty sure the problem is in the object initialization and not in the array.

Comment: My git repo, see model, controller, view, and main files.  https://github.com/cxx6xxc/Skeleton/commits/master

Comment: You can see clearly in controller.m that model and view are both passed.  In regard to the empty argument above, there are no missing arguments.  They are not 'empty arguments' they are empty labels that are really part of the function.

Comment: I appears I need to find the conventions on colon placement.  I see this is why you thought my args were labels.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you put a breakpoint in both your init and getLabels methods, and check the value of the instance variable that stores the array: you'll see which method does not behave as expected.

Comment: I can't afford XCode.  It's not free with a Linux box.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you are not using ARC nor synthesising variable labels, you need to retain the array,

```
- (id)init:
{
 labels = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Red", @"Green", @"Blue", nil];

 [labels retain];

 return self;    
}
```

Also, you need to release it when not using the array to prevent memory leakage.

Comment: I didn't declare autorelease.  But, I can try.

Comment: retain: had no effect.  Still null.

Comment: arrayWithObjects returns an array with autorelease. Can you show us more code? You may have assigned to another variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way, hoping in .h you have `NSMutableArray *labels;` :

```
- (id)init{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        labels = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Red", @"Green", @"Blue", nil];
    }
    return self;    
}
```

Comment: I have implemented correctly, as you refereed.  Tried the above, but still:2012-12-26 06:33:38.291 executable[13300] labels: (null)

Comment: try if(labels) nslog(@"allocated") else nslog(@"not alloced");

Comment: I tried this in init:, but NSLog seems not to work there.  I tried (using your alloc suggestion), but still comes back as not alloced.  All code:https://github.com/cxx6xxc/Skeleton

Answer (score 0):

The init method to model was never called, it is only allocated.  Therefore, NSArrray labels doesn't exist, because it is created in the init method.